# UNDEF Keyword in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, I am trying to use UNDEF keyword for a undefined variable in Ansible to overwrite with a default value when the variable itself is not defined based on the link provided here [reference document for Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

And to my dismay, did not see any practical example of a playbook or a role using this. Is there anyone has practical example which uses UNDEF keyword for a variable and defining with a default value when the variable is not defined?

I have already used not defined and undefined when conditions using jinja 2 templating. This is more about the UNDEF keyword itself.

Comment: There is an example in the doc your pointing at: `galaxy_api_key: {{ undef(hint="You must specify your Galaxy API key") }}`

Comment: yes, I have tried it inside the roles/default/main.yml but its not working. More specifically, based on the documentation, it does not say how to provide a value when a variable is undefined.  As Ansible uses Jinja2 template, I tried here https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#undefined-types but there is no practical example to utilize this jinja templating..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are kind of mixing two things here:

- The possibility to have a custom hint in the error Ansible would raise when a variable is undefined, with the [`undef` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-mandatory-values).
- The possibility to define a [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) when a variable is not defined.

Those two concepts are mutually exclusive, basically, because a variable having a `default` should never be undefined and should never cause Ansible to raise an error.
Although, depending on where you place your `default`, the way Ansible process variable could make the `undef` take precedence, and, so if you call a role containing an `undef`, then the error will always be raised.

As an example, a role variable file containing:

```yaml
demo_variable: "{{ undef(hint='Please provide a demo variable') | default('Defeat `undef` purpose') }}"
```

makes nearly no sense, as the default will always take precedence.

---

Here is a simple role using the `undef` keyword.

*roles/demo/vars/main.yml*:

```yaml
demo_variable: "{{ undef(hint='Please provide a demo variable') }}"
```

*roles/demo/tasks/main.yml*:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ demo_variable }}"
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
    - role: demo
```

If used as is, this will raise:

> ```
> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
> The error was: {{ undef(hint='Please provide a demo variable') }}: Please provide a demo variable
>   
> The error appears to be in '/usr/local/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, 
> but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
> ```

As opposed to an undefined variable not using the `undef` keyword that would have raised:

> ```
> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
> The error was: 'demo_variable' is undefined
>  
> The error appears to be in '/usr/local/ansible/roles/demo/tasks/main.yml': line 1, column 3, 
> but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
> ```

---

If you want a default, on the other hand, you'll have to drop the definition of the variable, including the `undef` keyword out of the *variable/main.yml* file of the role and have a *tasks/main.yml* that would read:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ demo_variable | default('Defeat `undef` purpose') }}"
```

And this would then give the expected:

```
TASK [demo : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Defeat `undef` purpose
```

when the variable is not defined at the level of the playbook calling this role.

Comment: I tried without using roles as below (I also tried declaring an undefined under roles but with same error message, sample is )
- name: Setting undefined variable
       vars:
          var4: "{{undef(hint='Please provide or set a value for var4 variable')}}"
       debug:
         msg: "{{var4}}"

and the error was not displaying separately the hint message:

 FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{undef(hint='Please provide or set a value for var4 variable')}}: 'undef' is undefined\n
More importantly, it says UNDEF is UNDEFINED